# WIFI and Bluetooth not connecting at same time..on my Tauras keyboard

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I have the iPad 2 and it has always worked, however, I have had it paired with the WIFI and Bluetooth and it has worked for 2 years, for the past week it will not connect the Tauras AKB34 keyboard to the Bluetooth and the WIFI  at the same time.  I am unable to use the keyboard, but the iPad 2 still works manually.
I have tried everything I know and nothing works.

I cannot find any battery to change on the keyboard, if there is one.
Thanks for your help,
Nancy Doyle 
Maine.

Comment: It has to have a battery....keep looking...and that is a Targus , not Taurus. Taurus is a car made by Ford and sold in Europe (mainly Germany)

Answer (score 1):

It should have come with a charger, or you can use USB cable.

It has a rechargeable battery.

The keyboard has an internal battery that’s charged with the included miniUSB cable.